# Is it possible to add a list to an android keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard

I have a keyboard with keys and rows but I want a layout where there is a list and when the user click on it, it types it in. For example, instead of the usual keyboard with the alphabet, I want a list with the alphabet that scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

The next answer is just an idea that maybe can solve your problem.
Try to add a DrawerLayout as a menu in your activity. There just add a list with your alphabet array.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="false">
```

Then, add a Listener to your list which will edit your focus editText with the tabs that you will do in your list.

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer);

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    drawerToggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            menuItem.setChecked(true);
            onNavDrawerItemClick(menuItem.getItemId());
            return true;
        }
    });
  private void onNavDrawerItemClick(int navItemId) {
    //ceramos el Drawer al hacer click en una opcion
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    mSelectedNavItem = navItemId;

    showItem(navItemId);
}

private void showItem(int navItemId) {
    switch (navItemId) {
        case R.id.LetterB:
             if (getActivity().getCurrentFocus() !=null && getActivity().getCurrentFocus() instanceof EditText ) {
            EditText etFocus = (EditText) getActivity().getCurrentFocus();

            etFocus.setText(etFocus.getText() + result.toString());
        }
            break;

        case R.id.letterA:
            if (getActivity().getCurrentFocus() !=null && getActivity().getCurrentFocus() instanceof EditText ) {
            EditText etFocus = (EditText) getActivity().getCurrentFocus();

            etFocus.setText(etFocus.getText() + result.toString());
        }

            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("not implemented");
    }
}
```

There is your "keyboard". Finally, disabled the android Keyboard in your manifest with:

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity" 
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

Hope that it will give you a new idea or maybe solve your problem!

Comment: Is there a way to do it with a service instead of an activity? I'm using InputMethodService to design the custom keyboard.

Comment: I didn´t worked so much with services, but I think this can be helpful for what you want to do: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615

Comment: No, this just helps me create the keyboard with the keys. I've done that already. I just want to configure a specific key on the keyboard to open up a list of options but I can't seem to find the solution anywhere